# Android - Supports tablets' dimens.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to only scale the text depending on resolution, so i created:

```
/res/values-ldpi/dimens.xml
/res/values-mdpi/dimens.xml
/res/values-hdpi/dimens.xml
/res/values-xhdpi/dimens.xml
/res/values-xxhdpi/dimens.xml
```

but the last one is being ignored by 10" tablet. I want to have a well-sclaed texts via `dimens.xml` file. How to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for 10" tablet use:

*/res/values-sw720dp/*

for 7" tablet use:

*/res/values-sw600dp/*

Comment: What about changing the text size based on high density screens? Just curious because I have to do this as well, but for phones like the new Nexus 6P. Different dimens.xml seems better.

Comment: But don't this force me to rewrite all of my layouts? Isn't there any way to do it via dimens.xml? I think, rewriting all layouts with changing only font scale is senseless.

Comment: Oh, gnarf. You can use the identifier sw (=smallest width) for your values as well.

Comment: Will that work well? The next 5X and 6P both have a sw of 410dp, but the resolution and screen size is a big difference so it seems like it would look wrong on one of the devices: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/android-marshmallow-ready-for-devices.html

Comment: It is from Android Developers -> Providing Resources:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

It works pretty well, yes.